# Proving matrices of bilinear forms are congruent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

Trying to  prove that for any two matrices $A,B$ representing the same symmetric bilinear form $f:V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$, there is an invertible matrix $P$, such that $B = P^{T}AP$ ?

I have a method for constructing such $P$ by repeated change of bases (when it is a quadratic form) but can't see a way to prove this generally?

Comment: What do you mean "represent the same symmetric bilinear form." I assume that you mean $(V,A)$ and $(V,B)$ are isomorphic as quadratic spaces. Could you help us out with some context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a change of basis. Let $A$ and $B$ be the matrices of the same bilinear form, but with respect to two ordered bases $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and $\{y_1,\ldots,y_n\}$ respectively. Let $P$ be the matrix such that $y_j=\sum_ip_{ij}x_i$, i.e. the matrix such that $\sum_jc_jy_j=\sum_i(Pc)_ix_i$ for any $c\in\mathbb R^n$. Then $B=P^TAP$.

Answer (score 4):

You can't prove it because it is false.

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 &1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0\\ 0 &-1\end{pmatrix}$$

aren't congruent, since $PAP^T = PP^T$ is definite positive, so can't be $B$.

Another example? let $A$ be the identity matrix, and $B$ the zero matrix. $A\ne PBP^T=B$.

Comment: Are these matrices representing the same bilinear map though?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how your answer is relevant. The OP is talking about matrices of the *same* bilinear form with respect to two different bases.

Comment: @user1551 It WAS relevant, before the last edit, when the OP added the condition that the two forms have to represent the same bilinear form

Comment: I see. You are right.